# Correlation doesn't work when variable is selected from selectInput but runs perfectly fine otherwise

Tags: r, shiny, correlation

I am calculating `correlation` for **each country** between Number of **Daily Covid Cases** & **Daily Vaccination**.

There are **two df**, one for **Confirmed Cases** & other for **Vaccinations**:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(glue)
library(scales)
library(tidytext)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

file_url1 <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/ts_all_long4.csv"

file_url2 <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/vaccination_data.csv"

ts_all_long <- read.csv(url(file_url1))
vaccination_data <- read.csv(url(file_url2))

ts_all_long <- ts_all_long %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date))

vaccination_data <- vaccination_data %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date))
```

When I use above data to **run correlation** in `rmarkdown` then it works:

```
ts_all_long %>% 
  left_join(y = vaccination_data,
            by = c("Country.Region" = "location", "date", "continent", "iso3c" = "iso_code")) %>% 
  
  na.omit() %>% 

  group_by(Country.Region) %>% 

  summarise(COR = cor(Confirmed_daily, total_vaccinations),
            total_vaccinations_per_hundred = first(total_vaccinations_per_hundred)) %>% 
  
  
  arrange(COR) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  slice(c(1:15, ( n()-14): n() ))
```

**Issue:** When I use this inside `shiny` with `SelectInput` at `total_vaccinations` to make **dynamic Parameter** then it gives this error:

> Problem with `summarise()` input `COR`. [31mx[39m incompatible
> dimensions [34mi[39m Input `COR` is `cor(Confirmed_daily, as.numeric(input$id_vaccination_type))`. [34mi[39m The error
> occurred in group 2: Country.Region = "Argentina".

**ui**

```
fluidRow(
                 style = "border: 1px solid gray;",
                 h3("Vaccination to Cases Correlation Analysis"),
                 
                 column(4, style = "border: 1px solid gray;",
                        selectInput(inputId = "id_vaccination_type", label = "Choose Vaccination Parameter", 
                                    choices = c("total_vaccinations","people_vaccinated","people_fully_vaccinated"), 
                                    selected = "total_vaccinations")
                        ),
                 
                 column(8, style = "border: 1px solid gray;",
                        plotOutput("top_corr_countries", height = "550px") #
                 )
```

**Server**

```
corr_data <- reactive({
        
        corr_data <- ts_all_long %>% 
            left_join(y = vaccination_data,
                      by = c("Country.Region" = "location", "date", "continent", "iso3c" = "iso_code")) %>% 
            
            na.omit() %>% 
            
            group_by(Country.Region) %>% 
            
            summarise(COR = cor(Confirmed_daily, as.numeric(input$id_vaccination_type)) ,
                      total_vaccinations_per_hundred = first(total_vaccinations_per_hundred)) %>% 
            na.omit() %>% 
            arrange(COR) %>% 
            na.omit() %>% 
            slice(c(1:15, ( n()-14): n() ))
    })

output$top_corr_countries <- renderPlot({
        
        corr_data() %>% 
            
            ggplot(aes(x = COR , 
                       y = fct_reorder(Country.Region, -COR),
                       col = COR > 0))  +
            geom_point(aes(size = total_vaccinations_per_hundred)) +
            geom_errorbarh(height = 0, size = 1, aes(xmin = COR, xmax = 0)) +
            geom_vline(xintercept = 0, col = "midnightblue", lty = 2, size = 1) +
            
            theme(
                panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                legend.position = "NULL") +
            
            labs(title = glue("Top Countries by +/- Correlation with Vaccination as of {max(vaccination_data$date)}"),
                 subtitle = "Size is proportional to Vaccination per Population",
                 y = "", x = "Correlation",
                 caption = "Data source: covid19.analytics
       Created by: ViSa")
        
    })
```

NOTE: I have also published this problem in another link but it sounds more complex in there so I have tried to rephrase it in this one to make it simpler.

Other post: [Unable to renderPlot on adding a selectInput option for variable in shiny which runs perfectly fine otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67072951/unable-to-renderplot-on-adding-a-selectinput-option-for-variable-in-shiny-which)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input$id_vaccination_type` is a character string of the variable you want to select.

To actually select thevalues of that variable you can turn the name of the variable into a `sym`bol and evaluate it, for example with the bang-bang operator `!!`.

So one solution would be:

`cor(Confirmed_daily, as.numeric(!! sym(input$id_vaccination_type))`

I'm not sure if this will make your app work (I can't download the csv files on github and would prefer `dput` for a minimal example), but it should solve this specific problem.

There are other solutions to this problem. One is to use `get` instead of `!! sym(input))`. The other is to use `varSelectInput`, which returns actual names and not strings (so here the problem should not arise in the first place).

Comment: Thankyou @TimTeaFan, really Appreciate your help!!. I am new to shiny and have been stuck on this issue for a while now.